# Is there a way to make a postman request to a wordpress site that is in docker container?

Tags: wordpress, docker, api, postman

I'm trying to make a get request in postman (using woocommerce api) to a test wordpress site that I created in docker container

My docker-compose file looks like this:

```
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:8
    container_name: mysql
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    restart: always
    command: "--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: xx
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wpdbb
      MYSQL_USER: xx
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: xx
   
  wordpress:
    image: wordpress:5.6.1
    container_name: wordpress
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./wp-content:/var/www/html/wp-content
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wpdbb
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: xx
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: xx
    ports:
      - 8080:80
      - 433:433
```

I can connect to the site using `localhost:8080` and can also connect to the database using sql workbench.

In docker though, wordpress container is shown with port 433.

What I'm trying to do is make a get request in postman using `http://localhost:8080/wp-json/wc/v3/products/` to get back all the  products from the wordpress site, but it returns 404 not found.
I have put in the key and secret into 1auth authentication also.
I then tried it with `https://localhost:433/wp-json/wc/v3/products/` and I get back:

```
Error: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established
```

I hope somebody could help me with what to do or what I am doing wrong, because I can't seem to figure it out.

thanks

Comment: Could you paste your docker compose file inline? You can enclose source files in 3 backticks `\`\`\`` to format it in a monospace font.

Comment: `404` means your site is reachable but there is no page at that location, you should check  your wordpress code to see if that page exists in the code.

Comment: @Beefster Thanks, I have added it

Comment: @KrishnaChaurasia I haven't written any code actually, I just created the wordpress container and I am able to access the site using localhost:8080, I've also added woocommerce plugin to it. it returns 404 when i try to make a request using postman with this url + woocommerce api request

Answer (score 1):

Postman is returning 200 success now . I found a solution on WordPress support to do with woocommerce API plugin. The 'permalinks' settings in WordPress needed to be changed to other than 'default'. After I did this, Postman requests were returning data.
Thanks all for your suggestions